# param is missing or the value is empty: subscribeduser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[The Error I Get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn8nZ.png)

I get the error when I try to create a new `subscribeduser`, I sort of "fixed" it by converting `params.require(:subscribeduser).permit(:email)` to  `params.permit(:email)` but I don't feel right about it. How do I properly get rid of this error?

**SubscribedusersController**

```
class SubscribedusersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_subscribeduser, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @subscribedusers = Subscribeduser.all
  end

  def new
    @subscribeduser = Subscribeduser.new
  end

  def create
    @subscribeduser = Subscribeduser.new(subscribeduser_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @subscribeduser.save
        RegistrationMailer.thankyou_mail(@subscribeduser).deliver_now
        format.html { redirect_to @subscribeduser, notice: 'Subscribeduser was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @subscribeduser }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @subscribeduser.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def subscribeduser_params
    params.require(:subscribeduser).permit(:email)
  end
end
```

This is the Subscribeduser Form

```
 <%= form_for(subscribeduser,:html => {:id => 'signup-form' }) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
   <%= f.text_field :email, :name =>"email", :id => "signup-form", "placeholder" => "Email Address" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign Up!" %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
```

[This Is What My Console Shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZi5y.png)

Comment: please post your view as well and params you are getting in controller while creating the object

Comment: It clearly says :subscribeduser param is missing so something is wrong with your form

Comment: Could you look at the log and find the line where the params are printed? Could you add it to the question?

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell it means that your requiring the param subscribed user but your controller action is not receiving one.

Without seeing your view code or your params from the console it's tough to say exactly, but have a look at your console output and check the params that are being sent through to your controllers create action.

Edit (you've now given your console output and view):

If you have a look in your console output, you'll see the `subscribeduser` param that your controller is requiring is not being received in the params, therefore the create action is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely your form is not rendering the resource (subscribed user), I believe your are missing the `@` in your form_for

try this `form_for(@subscribeduser,:html => {:id => 'signup-form' })`

Basically as the error states you are missing the `subscribeduser` when the form posts.

I would recommend for your to read on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html